# What is limiting the port range for HTTPS in .NET Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https, iis-express, asp.net-core-2.2

In the *launchSettings.json* I have the following. It works and I can access Swagger and the rest of the page using *https://localhost:44300*.

```
{ ...
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52088",
      "sslPort": 44300
    }
  }, ...
}
```

When I alter *"sslPort": 44300* to e.g. *"sslPort": 44299*, I can still access the stuff by altering the URL accordingly.

However, when I set the value to 5100, I've noticed that the contents aren't accessible anymore. In fact, it seems that the working range is rather limited and only concentrated around 44300.

What is that about?!

I've turned off the firewall, just in case. In the config I've tried adding the urls like this. No changes in the behavior.

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  //.UseUrls("https://localhost/5100")
  .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

How can I force the app to run properly on the port of my choice?

Following [docs for .NET Core 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#options), I added the configuration of the redirection as follows. As feared, it had no effect on the issue.

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(_ =>
{
  _.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
  _.HttpsPort = 5100;
});
```

Noticing that the docs themselves suggest 5001 as an alternative port number, I'm starting to suspect that the issue might be located entirely elsewhere. I'v recreated the setup on a different machine and was able to reproduce the error. Still, both are computers configured by me, so it'd be great if someone not-me'ish could confirm the behavior.

I've got a tip to use Nmap to check the port answers and apparently there's something answering on the port 5100. The same can be confirmed using [TelNet](https://www.techtutsonline.com/powershell-alternative-telnet-command/). However, the Swagger as well as the calls using PostMan fail still...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [documentation for IIS Express](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/handling-url-binding-failures-in-iis-express#using-a-custom-ssl-port) states (my emphasis):

> If you want to test SSL access to your site, you can do this with IIS Express by using an SSL port between 44300 and 44399 and using the IIS Express self-signed certificate. **Trying to use SSL with a port outside this range results in a URL binding failure when your website is launched under IIS Express**.

There are instructions in the linked *learn.microsoft.com* page that cover how to configure your machine to allow this. The short version is:

1. WIN-R > mmc.exe
2. File Menu > Add/Remove Snap-in...
3. Choose *Certificates* in the left-hand side and click the `Add >` button
4. Choose *Computer Account*, `Next >` and then `Finish`
5. Click `Ok` to dismiss the *Add or Remove Snap-ins* window
6. Expand Certificates (Local Computer) > Personal > Certificates in the treeview on the left-hand side
7. Find the certificate issued to *localhost* with a Friendly Name of *IIS Express Development Certificate* > Double click to open it
8. Move to the *Details* tab and scroll all the way down to find the *Thumbprint*
9. Copy & Paste the value out (click on it in the listview and the value will be dropped into the text field at the bottom of the window)

Now you've captured the thumbprint for the certificate:

1. Open a command prompt as administrator
2. Run the command `netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:5100 certhash=**Insert_Thumbprint_From_Step_9_Above_Here** appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}`
3. Restart IIS Express / your debugging session

IIS Express should now bind to 5100 (you can change the port in the command in step 2 above to one of your choice), letting Visual Studio pop a browser window that loads your site.

Comment: Or simply use an open source tool like Jexus Manager https://jexusmanager.com/ to simplify the steps.

Comment: I've been so unaware of that. Asking around among people in my network (some of whom have 10+ years of experience and sometimes more) gave nothing. It was virtually impossible to get any google hits on this, neither. How did you find out?

Comment: @DonkeyBanana, a vague recollection of having hit this issue before and then luck in hitting the right search terms to find the documentation to evidence it :) Stretching the realms of believability, my go to search engine is Bing - for me it seems to be better at finding MSFT related results than Google, though that's a relatively new thing :)

Comment: @LexLi, accept more pull requests, get more contributors to improve the reputation of your tool. 1 contributor doesn't spell much for continuity

Comment: I just lost 1.5 hours of my life trying to figure out why my port 44405 is not working.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ you're not the first, you won't be the last, and being completely honest... since writing this answer I have *again* hit this issue and taken a non-zero amount of time to remember the solution. It is more than a little obscure 

Answer (score -1):

There will be an IIS Express icon running in your toolbar.  Stop the site under port 44300 through IIS Express and restart the site again and it should now run through your new port.  If that doesn't work, just exit IIS Express and restart the site.

[image]

Comment: I'm going to try that when I get home. However, I'm curious if you've got any thoughts on why the change in of port value takes effect without your suggestion as long as it's around the previous value. Such weirdness usually imply that there's something else that governs the process...

Comment: Naa, it was like I suspected. The ports I can see in the IIS Express thingy on the toolbar change according to the *launchSettings.json* (it disregards *.UseUrls(...)*). However, I can't access e.g. Swagger when the port is set to too low value (such as 5100, for instance).

Comment: That is really weird.  I was able to reproduce what you were experiencing by changing the port in the launchSettings.json and then still being able to access swagger on the original port.  It wasn't until I existed IIS Express and restarted the app that I was then unable to access swagger on the original port and needed to access on the new port.  Are you able to try and Incognito tab in chrome, just to rule out caching?

Comment: Good idea. Tested it now and it behaves as expected in the regard of port switching (you need to re-launch the application because the *launchsettings.json* is only read during, well... the launch). However, can you confirm that if you change the secure port to something like 5100 (i.e. way lower than the 443xx range), the application starts but doesn't serve stuff properly? It sems to work as expected on HTTP when I comment out *app.UseHttpsRedirection();*... So it might be an issue with HTTPS but more than that is outside of my competence.